# Why npx create-react-app my-first-app is not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

Tried to run `npx create-react-app` but I am getting errors and cannot run command. Can you help?

[Terminal Screenshot with stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5blkU.png)

````sh
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Mizanur'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorMessage (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-message.js:38:39)
    at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:201:13)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
    at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:225:22)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:263:24
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:13
    at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:171:20)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97
  var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97:27)
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:164:25)
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 7```
````

Comment: Try to install in another drive (not in C) to understand if it's restricted from the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a system issue with your computer. It seems the `create-react-app` script doesn't have permission to write the folder `'C:\Users\Mizanur'`.

Can you do *anything* with npx? For example does `npx cowsay moo` work?

EDIT: Appears others have had this issue, there are some possible answers here: https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/100#issuecomment-344293820

Seems you should try to run the cmd prompt as an administrator or fix your npm cache location if there's a space in your Windows username.